# Magento 2 : Add custom script just after head tag

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2

i want to add custom script just after the start of head tag.

like.

```
<head>
<script>console.log("I'm loaded!");</script>
```

i tried to add code in default_head_blocks.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
      <block class="Custom\Module\Block\Success" template="Custom_Module::success/head.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

=> output :

```
<script>console.log("I'm loaded!");</script>
</head>
```

this code are using add script before the end of head tag.

Please check Below code

**Block => Custom/Module/Block/Onepage/Success.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Block\Onepage;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

    class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success {

    public function getOrder() 
        {
            $objectManager =\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $helper = $objectManager->get('Custom\Module\Helper\Data');

            $lastOrderId = $this->getOrderId();

            if (empty($lastOrderId)) 
            {
                return null;
            }
              $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());

            return $orderData;
        }

    }
```

**Helper => Custom\Module\Helper\Data.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     */
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
         $this->_request = $request;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }
     public function getConfigValue($value = '') {
        return $this->scopeConfig
                ->getValue($value,\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
    public function getTemplate()
    {
        if ($this->getConfigValue('custom_general/general/active') == 1) {
            $template =  'Custom_Module::checkout/success.phtml';
        } else {
            $template = 'Magento_Checkout::success.phtml';
        }

        return $template;
    }
}
```

**di.xml => etc\di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="Custom\Module\Block\Onepage\Success"/>
</config>
```

**Layout Xml => Custom/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="require.js">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Module::success/head.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock> 
    </body>
</page>
```

**Template => Custom/Module/view/frontend/templates/success/head.phtml**

```
<script>
    console.log("I'm loaded!");

</script>
```

Please help me and solve this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the correct way or not, but I have got a lead.

By default magento 2 usees the `root.phtml` file to setup `head` content accordingly, which is located in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml` (if it has not been overridden).

Here, the `$requireJs` variable is loaded first in the head block. The `$requireJs` variable is defined in the `render` method inside `Page` class -which is located in `vendor/magento/framework/view/Result/Page.php`.

In this file, `$requireJs` contains the `require.js` block. And the `require.js` block is defined in `vendor/Magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` :

```
<block name="require.js" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::page/js/require_js.phtml" />
```

**Solution**

1)  Copy `require_js.phtml` from `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js` to your theme `app/design/frontend/{VENDOR}/{THEME_NAME}/Magento_Theme/templates/page/js/`

2) Now you can add your script like this:

```
<script>
    console.log("I'm loaded!");

    var require = {
        "baseUrl": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('/') ?>"
    };
</script>
```

**UPDATE (Using Module)**

Overriding the `require.js` block is not an elegant solution. if anyone has a good solution please answer. For now edit your layout xml:

```
<referenceBlock name="require.js">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Module::success/head.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

and inside `success/head.phtml` add your code:

```
<script>
    console.log("I'm loaded!");
    var require = {
        "baseUrl": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('/') ?>"
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay,

Comment: but i don't want to add script in require_js.phtml and root.phtml because i didn't  added custom theme , it's my custom module so.

Comment: @SandipDutt ! please check the updated answer if it helps you or not?

Comment: @SandipDutt could you please share you code for better understanding?

Comment: Ok but when i added your solution in default.xml it getting error like
 invalid method Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template for action set template

can you share your code here?

Comment: @SandipDutt Nice! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way of doing it that seems very reasonable, because it uses existing features in the `adminhtml` theme without any need to override/intercept anything.

#### Background

Like @sanchit-gupta mentioned, the `root.phtml` template is used as the basis to render both the `frontend` and `adminhtml` areas, and so is the associated class `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page`, which always looks for a block named `head.additional` before rendering.

This block exists in the `frontend` layouts by default, but unfortunately it doesn't exist in the `adminhtml` layout.

#### Solution

With that in mind, the current best way (as of 2.3.x) to add inline `<scripts>` to the `adminhtml`'s `<head>` section is to add any `head.additional` block: it will be automatically rendered by the framework. It either has to be a `ListText` block so that it renders all it's children automatically, or a `Template` with a specified template file. I actually chose too nest my actual block inside the `ListText` block just to keep the same mechanism available as in the `frontend` area (i.e. for compatibility with other plugins that might be doing the same).

#### Example

In your custom module or theme, add a layout update that inserts the following block into the `body` of the page layout (which is just to do it the same way as it's done in Magento 2 core for the `frontend` area):

```xml
<body>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="head.additional">
        <block name="your_block" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Your_Module::your/template.phtml" />
    </block>
</body>
```

Done! Your template will render inside `<head></head>` – without any awkward overrides or "hacks".

What's more, if other modules also reference `head.additional` in the `adminhtml` area, they will be compatible with your code.